# Can I point an Azure CDN at an Azure Traffic Manager?

Tags: azure, cdn

I have a large website hosted in Azure. There are a number of virtual servers (my-web-server-1.cloudapp.net, my-web-server-2.cloudapp.net, etc) behind a Traffic Manager (my-lb.trafficmanager.net).

When I've been setting up similar sites in the past, I usually point the CDN origin at the load balancer, so it doesn't matter if one of my servers is offline at any point.

Azure CDN doesn't seem to let you do this. 
When I click on "Quick Create", and select a subscription, my origin options are:

1. Some blob storage accounts that seem to correspond to the VHDs for my servers.
2. http://my-web-server-1.cloudapp.net/cdn/
3. http://my-web-server-2.cloudapp.net/cdn/

No sign of the LB, and no option to serve files from any other directory than "/cdn/".

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on the feature list, but no ETA on when it will be available.  You would need to sign up for a different, non-Azure CDN provider to get this functionality today.

Answer (score 2):

Please select "Custom Origin" as the Origin type when you configure the endpoint and provide your TM endpoint as the Origin. 
We suggest you start using the new Azure Portal at https://portal.azure.com and "browse" to "CDN Profiles" to start using new and advanced features of Azure CDN.